# compiling caffe with cudnn installed in HOME directory(without root priviledg): cannot find lcudnn

Tags: cuda, caffe

recently came across a problem when compiling caffe on a server, prompts `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudnn`
since I don't have `root priviledge`, I installed `CUDA-8.0` in my `HOME` directory, then download the `libcudnn7-dev` and manually do `dpkg-deb -xv libcudnn-dev*.deb` to extract the deb pkg, then I go to the lib directory, then run `ar -x libcudnn*.a` and `gcc -shared *.o -o libcudnn.so`, then copy the generated `libcudnn.so` to `~/cuda/lib64`, then add the `~/cuda/lib64` to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but the error prompts, I don't know how to fix this, can someone help?

And I don't understand why it is `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudnn`, not something like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH/=: cannot find -lcudnn`

EDIT:
I downloaded the .tgz file and follow the install guide instructions to install cudnn, but it still prompts the error, my ~/.bashrc is configured:

`export CUDA_HOME="~/cuda" 
export PATH="/home/wangtao/anaconda2/bin:$CUDA_HOME/bin:$PATH" 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$CUDA_HOME/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"`

I find the `/etc/ld.so.conf` is like this :

`include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf /usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64` 
it is not my wanted path of `~/cuda/lib64`, but don't know how to modify it since I don't have root priviledge on the server, I have compiled successfully on local machines, but this seems to be hard

Comment: Not sure what you did or why.  Download CUDNN from developer.nvidia.com and install it according to the instructions there.  You will then have a proper libcudnn that you can link against. You won't need to use `ar` or `gcc` to create the `.so` library.  You will need to sign up as a registered developer if you have not already done so.  When linking, the linker here is `/usr/bin/ld`, which is why you are getting that message.  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has to do with the runtime dynamic linker/loader system, it is not involved in compile-time linking.

Comment: Thank you, I don't follow the standard installation procedure because I don't have the `root priviledge` to do it(as it involves deb pkg which cannot be installed without root), could you suggest where I can add the path of `libcudnn.so` so that the linker in `/usr/bin/ld` can find it? is `/etc/ld.so.conf` the place?(but I don't have root priviledge to modify it)

Comment: You don't need root privilege to do any of this, and you don't need the deb package.  Go to the [download page](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download) get the [cudnn library for linux](https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/cudnn/secure/v7.0.5/prod/9.0_20171129/cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7) (not the deb) and follow the install guide instructions, specifically the section "install from tar file"

Comment: Thank you, I downloaded the .tgz file and follow the install guide instructions to install cudnn, but it still prompts the error, my `~/.bashrc` is configured:
`export CUDA_HOME="~/cuda"
export PATH="/home/wangtao/anaconda2/bin:$CUDA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$CUDA_HOME/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
` I find the `/etc/ld.so.conf` is like this :
`include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64`, seems not right

Comment: We are not here to help you, we are here to answer your programming questions. So ask a clear, straightforward question,, and then you might get an answer which helps you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We newbies need to learn more, maybe other people sometimes would not help you much, help yourself, learn more!
Turns out that linking is different from dynamic loading, linking done pre to dynamic loading, what `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` can affect is dynamic loading, which gives the library file path(eg, `.so.1.0`, not `.so` which is usually a symlink to `.so.1.0` stuffs and is used for linker not loader), so adding the `libcudnn.so` path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` does not help, what `/usr/bin/ld` complains is that linker cannot find the cudnn library, so we need to add `libcudnn.so` path for the linker to find it, which is what `LIBRARY_PATH` cames to help, just add it to it, then linker can find it, sometimes we are just not on the right direction, do not annoying, just learning more:)

Comment: Note that with root priviledge, the kind of installing and compilation is very easy, but my case is without the priviledge